# Checking member function overload existence from a template

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Is it possible to check whether a class has a certain member function overload from within a template member function?

The best similar problem I was able to find is this one: [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) As I understand it, this doesn't apply in to the case of checking for overloads of functions.

Here a simplified example of how this would be applied:

```
struct A;
struct B;

class C
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void doSomething(std::string asdf)
    {
        T data_structure;

        /** some code */

        if(OVERLOAD_EXISTS(manipulateStruct, T))
        {
            manipulateStruct(data_structure);
        }

        /** some more code */
    }

private:
    void manipulateStruct(B& b) {/** some different code */};
}
```

My question would be if some standard way exists to make the following usage of the code work:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    C object;
    object.doSomething<A>("hello");
    object.doSomething<B>("world");
    exit(0);
}
```

The only methods I could think of would be to simply create an emtpy overload of `manipulateStruct` for struct `A`. Otherwise the manipulation method could of course also be put into the structs to be manipulated, which would make SFINAE an option. Let's assume both of these to not be a possiblity here.

Is there any way to get code similar to the above one to work? Does something similar to `OVERLOAD_EXISTS` exist, to let the compiler know when to add the `manipulateStruct` part to the generated code? Or is there maybe some way clever way to make SFINAE work for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Testing overload existence (C++11)

Since C++11, you can use a mix of [std::declval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) and [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to test for the existence of a specific overload:

```
// If overload exists, gets its return type.
// Else compiler error
decltype(std::declval<C&>().manipulateStruct(std::declval<T&>()))
```

This can be used in a SFINAE construct:

```
class C {
public:
    // implementation skipped
private:
    // Declared inside class C to access its private member.
    // Enable is just a fake argument to do SFINAE in specializations.
    template<typename T, typename Enable=void>
    struct can_manipulate;
}

template<typename T, typename Enable>
struct C::can_manipulate : std::false_type {};

// Implemented outside class C, because a complete definition of C is needed for the declval.
template<typename T>
struct C::can_manipulate<T,std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<C&>().manipulateStruct(std::declval<T&>()))>> : std::true_type {};
```

Here I am ignoring the return type of the overload using [std::void_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) (C++17, but C++11 alternatives should be possible). If you want to check the return type, you can pass it to [std::is_same](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) or [std::is_assignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable).

## doSomething implementation

#### C++17

This can be done with [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(std::string asdf) {
    T data_structure;
    if constexpr (can_manipulate<T>::value) {
        manipulateStruct(data_structure);
    }
}
```

The `if constexpr` will make the compiler discards the `statement-true` if the condition evaluates to false. Without the `constexpr`, the compilation will require the function call inside the `if` to be valid in all cases.

[Live demo (C++17 full code)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TDViHTc96iFzqmSc)

#### C++11

You can emulate the `if constexpr` behaviour with SFINAE:

```
class C {
    // previous implementation
private:
    template<typename T, typename Enable=void>
    struct manipulator;
}

template<typename T, typename Enable>
struct C::manipulator {
    static void call(C&, T&) {
        //no-op
    }
};

// can_manipulate can be inlined and removed from the code
template<typename T>
struct C::manipulator<T, typename std::enable_if<C::can_manipulate<T>::value>::type> {
    static void call(C& object, T& local) {
        object.manipulateStruct(local);
    }
};
```

Function body:

```
template<typename T>
T doSomething()
{
    T data_structure;
    // replace if-constexpr:
    manipulator<T>::call(*this, data_structure);
}
```

[Live demo (C++11 full code)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FlRIeC1ZBo2vLDWr)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sadly I'm working in C++11 at the moment, but it still is very cool that this type of code is possible under C++17 with if constexpr

Comment: @abcalphabet I added a (verbose) workaround for C++11.

Comment: Perfect, the C++11 workaround works for me, thank you very much!